# Eliminar duplicados de una lista de string usando Set() en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Usando `Set()` tengo que mostrar una lista de valores únicos, pero no logro eliminarlos.

Esto es lo que tengo hecho:

```
# Solicitar lista de paises
paises = input("Lista de paises (separados por coma): ")

# convertir la entrada a una lista separando por coma
lista_paises = paises.split(',')

# guardar el conjunto sin duplicados
lista_paises = set(lista_paises)
lista_paises = list(set(lista_paises))

print(lista_paises)
```

Y esta es la salida

> Lista de paises (separados por coma): es, es, fr, it

> ['es', ' it', ' es', ' fr']

Como se ve, no está eliminando los duplicados, y además, los coloca en otro orden, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Probe el código con el ejemplo y me responde correctamente: `[' fr', ' es', ' it']`.

Comment: Basta con `lista_paises = list(lista_paises)`, pues en la línea previa ya la convertistes en un `set()`.

Comment: Pues que raro, lo he vuelto a ejecutar y me salen duplicados, lo estoy ejecutando con 3.10 y vscode

Comment: Eso ocurre por que hay unos espacios entre las palabras, primero deberás eliminarlos. `list(set(letra.strip() for letra in paises.split(","))`

Comment: @Christian ha funcionado a la perfección, ¡gracias!

Comment: debes cerrar la pregunta si ya fue contestada

Comment: @MARCELOBRAVO ninguna de las opciones para cerrar la pregunta es que ya está resuelta, al menos, yo no la veo, si pongo otro motivo, la pregunta se cerraría, salvo error por mi parte, por un criterio incorrecto.

Comment: Debe ser porque no tirne respuestas y solo comentarios. Podrias autocontestarte con el codigo del comentario que te resolvio la duda y ahi te permitira cerrarla

Comment: Cierto, pero estaba también esperando a que el autor de la solución lo haga. Lo añado yo puesto que han pasado varios días y no lo ha puesto. Gracias @MARCELOBRAVO por la sugerencia :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución la ha dado Christian en los comentarios.

> Eso ocurre por que hay unos espacios entre las palabras, primero deberás eliminarlos.
> `list(set(letra.strip() for letra in paises.split(","))`